# How to define manual maximum bandwidth for Linksys WRET45GL

Tags: networking, bandwidth

I need to study the impact of increase in number of concurrent users on a LAN throughput. The data size is about 500KB and bandwidth is 4Mbps. Here is my questions:

1. Can I do it in real testbed or should I run simulation?
2. If real testbed works, how can I define manual network bandwidth in Linksys WRT45GL router.

On a real testbed, I can run a javascript code to send asynchronous data fetch request to a web server in the same network (on different machines), but my question is how to define manual network bandwidth there and make sure that it won't change throughout the study. I can isolate the network and disable wireless network too.

In case of simulation, what is the simplest and the most reliable one to help  me in doing such a simple task.

Sorry if it is too simple.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use `iperf`. It's a client-server software package that allows you to simulate a specified amount of bandwidth.

The "right" way to run iperf is to have a client at one end and a server at the other, but if you just need to flood a link with a controlled amount of traffic, you can get away with running the iperf client using UDP. But this depends on your situation.

You could use a syntax for the client like so:

```
iperf -c 180.92.196.115 -u -p 5001 --time 360 -i 3 -b 2
```

This specifies:

- Run iperf in client mode.
- Use UDP instead of TCP
- Send traffic to UDP port 5001
- Run the test for 360 seconds
- Report on the bandwidth stats every 3 seconds
- Generate a constant 2 Mbits worth of UDP traffic for the test.

You need to make sure that the two end-points of iperf correspond with the traffic flow you're trying to test. For example, if I'm trying to saturate the internet link to test VoIP QoS settings over a WAN, it's not going to help me to run iperf between two PCs on the LAN. That traffic would not pass over the WAN and therefore have no impact.

So you may find you'll need to run the iperf server software on an actual hosted server, outside of the LAN.

### Real Network or Simulator?

That's up to you, really. The tools to do the testing would be the same either way, in my opinion. Obviously if you want to run it over a production network, either schedule it outside of normal business hours, or do it in some way to avoid impact to the users.

I prefer doing the tests on the real network, if I can, because that way you get to deal with a more "real world" scenario. Trying to simulate a real network can be tough, and your results might not be as accurate because you forgot to simulate one of the many variables of the network.

So it's usually easier and more accurate to use the real thing.

### An Example

I use it regularly to verify QoS deployments for VoIP customers. Typically I will run the test over their real network, with and without QoS enabled to verify an improvement. Obviously your test is different, but the methodology would be similar.

### Testing User Growth

Iperf will only simulate the amount of bandwidth you tell it to - the amount of traffic used "per user" varies depending on your situation, so obviously there's no way to guess that.

The way I would approach this problem is:

- Setup interface monitoring graphs for the LAN.
- Take note of how many concurrent users there are throughout the day and how much bandwidth (bits per second) is being used on the interface at those times.
- Or, take note of the average bandwidth used throughout a business day, and the average concurrent users each day. Then use these figures to determine a rough "bandwidth per user" amount.

If you can figure out a base line bandwidth amount per user, then you can run multiple iperf tests to simulate. Eg. If you figure that each user consumes an average of 0.25 Mbps, then you could say that to simulate 10 users, you need to generate 2.5 Mbps of traffic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but why only UDP? Moreover, how can I increase number of users? I need to study impact of user growth on network output.

Comment: @Espanta As mentioned, I use this with UDP, but you can do TCP also. I only use UDP because then I don't have to setup an iperf server, but it's up to you. I will edit the question regarding testing of user growth.

Comment: @Espanta If you have sufficient bandwidth to the server and client, you can use the `--parallel` option to open up multiple concurrent connections to simulate multiple users.